# Listener does not currently know of SID

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g, connection, database-connection

I am unable to connect to my database every once in a while. Following is the message I get.

```
Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor
```

`I know the SID I am using is correct.` This error goes away if I just restart my computer. The instance of the oracle database that I am trying to connect to runs locally on my computer.

This wastes a lot of my time, just restarting the computer every time this happens.

Answer (score 0):

This is caused due to the fact that your archives are taking up your table space. When you reboot the archive space is recovered and you're able to connect.

You'll need to increase the size of your database files.